# How to loop through every line in a file and use them as a condition to loop though directories?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a file in a directory that contains some lines, say 10. In that directory I have other sub-directories, say 100. What I want is: go to each sub-directory which ‘match’ with the sub-directory name exists in the file. So, basically I want a sort of ‘match string’ condition which will compare each line of the file and each sub-directories and then go to a specific sub-directory when there is a match.

The file looks like:

```
SCEL16_4_2_2_0_0_2
SCEL1_1_1_1_0_0_0
SCEL32_4_4_2_2_2_0
SCEL32_4_4_2_2_2_0
SCEL32_4_4_2_2_2_0
SCEL32_4_4_2_2_2_0
SCEL32_4_4_2_2_2_0
SCEL32_4_4_2_2_2_0
SCEL8_8_1_1_0_0_7
SCEL8_8_1_1_0_0_6
```

And the directory has around 100 or more sub-directories with similar namings. I need a way to go through only these 10 sub-directories mentioned in the file. I tried doing something like:

```
for i in */; do echo $i; done
```

which tells me all the sub-directories present in the current directory but I am not getting how do I impose the 'match' condition here within the above command. Is there any quick get around to solve this?

Comment: `for d in $(<your_file); do echo $d; done`???

Comment: `grep $i file && echo "Do something with directory $i"`

Comment: @oguzismail: thanks, it was really simple, didn't think about it!

Answer (score 0):

Lets, say file containing the list is "list_dirs"

Use similar to below logic

```
for dir in list_dirs; do
perm=$(ls -la $dir 2>/dev/null);
if [-n $perm ]; 
then 
    // here do whatever is need if it matches
else
    // else part here
fi
```

Logic:

`ls -la` will check if the directory is present or not and as `2>/dev/null` is there it will make the perm variable empty.